# just have background after install

Tags: updates

I have just completed upgrade from 13.03 to 14.04. After logging in just have the background, no menus, no nothing, mouse travels across screen but keyboard does not appear to to work

Anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Ubuntu's gui isn't completely starting up, or is mis-configured. I don't know what exactly could be wrong, you could be missing graphic or other hardware drivers or something mysterious. Maybe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, or ...<kbd>F8</kbd> ...<kbd>F1</kbd> etc might have some interesting messages or get you to a terminal to see how mount looks or read logs or whatnot? But I'd take the opportunity now to backup any important data you don't want deleted, if it isn't too late already, Booting from a live CD/DVD/USB should be up to the backup task.

I've always read that upgrading Ubuntu has historically been a bad idea, it might often work, but it might often mess things up, like this. A better upgrade strategy advised has been to backup your home directory/data, backup any other data (maybe put them on a separate partition or disk, and if they're really important make a REAL backup to something that can be unplugged or some cloud) and then erase your old 13.04 (probably not 13.03 right?) and install 14.04. Then you can use your old home files if you want. If it were me, I'd backup, install 14.04 fresh, and then use old home.

Here's some good-looking info I found about Help for booting problems, the linked answer is specifically what to do "If an update or something else caused your boot problem" https://askubuntu.com/a/162078/129271  It's too much info to copy & paste here, 9 different steps/tips based on your specific hardware & type of problem, and the main question looks helpful too.